# How to convert list of lists to dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am using `quantmod` to download option chains which come in the form of nested lists.

However for my purposes I would rather have the information in the form of a dataframe where the name of each list is contained in a column of the dataframe (thus two columns would be needed one containing the date of the strike of the option and the second the type of the option -- call or put).

How can this be accomplished in R?

For a reproducible example:

```
library(quantmod)
AAPL.2015 <- getOptionChain("AAPL", "2019/2021")
```

[image]

And if possible, what I should do to get the dates of the option strikes in English?

Comment: Are you sure it is `Quandl` instead of `quantmod`?

Comment: also, for converting list of lists into dataframes, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019884/how-to-remove-observations-from-multiple-dataframes-and-keep-as-multiple-datafra/58020054#58020054

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your example, but what you're trying to do is simple. You could use `do.call` to call the `rbind` function on the list and what you get at the end is a pretty dataframe.

```
list <- getOptionChain("AAPL", "2019/2021")

data <- do.call(rbind, list)
```

Comment: Interesting that this works with nested lists unless there is no *calls* and *puts*!

Answer (score 1):

Consider `Map` to `rbind` the individual calls and puts data frames adding needed indicator columns. Because the individual data frames resides within a nested, named list, the extract function, `[` is used.

Then, run a final `do.call` + `rbind` across resulting list of data frames. NOTE: `rbind` assumes the call and put data frames maintain exact same names and number of columns.

```
call_put_func <- function(nm, call_df, put_df) {      
     cbind(rbind(transform(call_df, option_type = "call"),
                 transform(put_df, option_type = "put")
           ), date_of_strike = nm)
}

APPL_flat_df_list <- Map(call_put_func, nm = names(AAPL.2015), 
                                        call_df = lapply(AAPL.2015, "[[", "calls"), 
                                        put_df = lapply(AAPL.2015, "[[", "puts")
                        )

APPL_df <- do.call(rbind, unname(APPL_flat_df_list))
```

Comment: I am getting an error: Error in (function (nm, call_df, put_df) : unused arguments (calls = dots[[2]][[1]], puts = dots[[3]][[1]])
Traceback:

1. Map(call_put_func, nm = names(AAPL.2015), calls = lapply(AAPL.2015, 
 .     `[`, "calls"), puts = lapply(AAPL.2015, `[`, "puts"))
2. mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

Comment: I still get error message: Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)): names do not match previous names
Traceback:

1. Map(call_put_func, nm = names(AAPL.2015), call_df = lapply(AAPL.2015, 
 .     `[`, "calls"), put_df = lapply(AAPL.2015, `[`, "puts"))
2. mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
3. (function (nm, call_df, put_df) 
 . {
 .     cbind(rbind(transform(call_df, option_type = "call"), transform(put_df, 
 .         option_type = "put")), date_of_strike = nm)
 . })(nm = dots[[1L]][[1L]], call_df = dots[[2L]][[1L]], put_df = dots[[3L]][[1L]])

Comment: 4. cbind(rbind(transform(call_df, option_type = "call"), transform(put_df, 
 .     option_type = "put")), date_of_strike = nm)   # at line 2-4 of file <text>
5. rbind(transform(call_df, option_type = "call"), transform(put_df, 
 .     option_type = "put"))
6. rbind(deparse.level, ...)
7. match.names(clabs, names(xi))
8. stop("names do not match previous names")

Comment: Check `colnames` of both *calls* and *puts*. Do they match exactly in spelling and number? Also, try doubling `[[` instead of single.

Answer (score 1):

It might be more flexible to work with a couple functions from `dplyr` and `purrr`. `dplyr::bind_rows` can take a list of data frames, and they can have different names, whereas the base `rbind` just works on 2 data frames at once. `bind_rows` also has an argument `.id` that will create a column of list item names. `purrr::map_dfr` calls a function over a list and returns a data frame of them all row-bound together; because it wraps around `bind_rows`, it also has an `.id` argument.

Having access to setting those IDs is helpful because you have 2 sets of IDs: one of dates, and one of calls vs puts. Setting one ID within the inner `bind_rows` and one within `map_dfr` gets both.

Written out with a function, to make it a little easier to see:

```r
library(quantmod)
AAPL.2015 <- getOptionChain("AAPL", "2019/2021")

aapl_df <- purrr::map_dfr(AAPL.2015, function(d) {
  dplyr::bind_rows(d, .id = "type")
  }, .id = "date")

head(aapl_df)
#>          date  type Strike  Last   Chg   Bid   Ask Vol OI
#> 1 Sep.27.2019 calls    140 79.50  9.50 77.60 77.90  10 30
#> 2 Sep.27.2019 calls    145 75.85  0.00 72.70 73.30  NA 28
#> 3 Sep.27.2019 calls    150 72.22  0.00 67.85 67.90  10 91
#> 4 Sep.27.2019 calls    155 52.53  0.00 65.80 69.90  NA 10
#> 5 Sep.27.2019 calls    160 60.10  0.00 57.85 58.15   2 11
#> 6 Sep.27.2019 calls    165 54.40 15.95 52.65 52.90   9 16
```

Or in more common `dplyr` piping with function shorthand notation:

```r
library(dplyr)
aapl_df <- AAPL.2015 %>%
  purrr::map_dfr(~bind_rows(., .id = "type"), .id = "date")
```